# How to filter posts in Vue with components and v-bind:class

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make an example based on this pen I got from here: 
https://codepen.io/conradolandia/pen/YzyPmrv

But I want to use vue-router, I've tried this: (pen: https://codepen.io/conradolandia/pen/vYNERPW)

HTML:

```
<main class="wrap">
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</main>

<template id="post-list-template">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h4>Filter by album:</h4>
            <div class="filters">
                <button class="btn" v-bind:class="{ active: currentFilter === 'ALL' }" v-on:click="setFilter('ALL')">all</button>
                <button class="btn" v-bind:class="{ active: currentFilter === 'art' }" v-on:click="setFilter('art')">art</button>
                <button class="btn" v-bind:class="{ active: currentFilter === 'doodles' }" v-on:click="setFilter('doodles')">doodles</button>
                <button class="btn" v-bind:class="{ active: currentFilter === 'workshops' }" v-on:click="setFilter('workshops')">workshops</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns is-multiline">
            <div class="column is-3" v-if="currentFilter === post.category || currentFilter === 'ALL'" v-bind:key="post.title" v-for="post in posts">
                <div class="card post">
                    <img class="card-img-top" v-bind:src="post.image">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</div>
                        <small class="tags">{{ post.category }}</small>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- .post -->
            </div> <!-- .col-md-4 -->
        </div> <!-- .row -->
    </div> <!-- .container -->
</template>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #ccc;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.post {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.post img{ width: 100%;}

.tags {background-color: #ccc; padding: 3px 5px;}

.filters {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
var postList = Vue.extend({

    template: "#post-list-template",

    data: function(){
        return {
            currentFilter:'ALL',
            posts: [
                {title: "Artwork", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=122", category: 'art'},
                {title: "Charcoal", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=116", category: 'art'},
                {title: "Sketching", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=121", category: 'doodles'},
                {title: "Acrillic", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=133", category: 'workshops'},
                {title: "Pencil", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=134", category: 'doodles'},
                {title: "Pen", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=115", category: 'art'},
                {title: "Inking", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200", category: 'workshops'},
                {title: "Artwork", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=121", category: 'art'},
                {title: "Charcoal", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=115", category: 'art'},
                {title: "Sketching", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=124", category: 'doodles'},
                {title: "Acrillic", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=13", category: 'workshops'},
                {title: "Pencil", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=14", category: 'doodles'},
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setFilter: function(filter) {
            this.currentFilter = filter;
        }
    },
})

// Start a new instance of router (instead of router.map)
var router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: postList }
    ]
})

// Start a new instance of the Application required (instead of router.start)
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
})
```

So far, no luck. The filter *kind of* works, the first click I make activates a filtering option, but then all filters stop working, and firefox complains with "TypeError: "e is undefined"".

Can somebody point me in the right direction, please? I don't understand why the first codepen link works but the second doesn't.

Clarifying: When I click any filter, filters kind of work, but if I click the "ALL" filter, everything stops working.

Comment: I tried running your codepen in both Chrome and Firefox but I wasn't able to reproduce the error you reported. Clicking the buttons seems to filter the images for me.

Comment: @Rijosh's answer works great.

Comment: It *kind of* worked before (now it works as it should), some times would be fine, but eventually would break while changing filters and throw the error in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a computed function

```
computed:{
  filteredPosts:function(){
    if(this.currentFilter==='ALL'){
       return this.posts;
    }
    return this.posts.filter(post=>{
      return post.category === this.currentFilter;
    })
  }
}
```

You can use `filteredPosts` instead of `posts` while looping

```
    <div class="columns is-multiline">
        <div class="column is-3" :key="post.title" v-for="post in filteredPosts">
            <div class="card post">
                <img class="card-img-top" :src="post.image">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</div>
                    <small class="tags">{{ post.category }}</small>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- .post -->
        </div> <!-- .col-md-4 -->
    </div> <!-- .row -->
```

You don't need to use any condition while looping, since the `computed` function will do the job.