# Vuejs blog post tag filter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, tags

I'm currently building an app with Vue.js and firebase and I'm trying to add a filter by tag functionality to my blog component.

I'm doing so:

```
matters () {
        return this.$store.getters.loadedMatters
      },
      footprints () {
        return this.$store.getters.loadedFootprints
      },
      filteredMatters: function () {
        if (this.currentFilter === "all") {
          return this.matters;
        }
        return this.matters.filter((matter) => {
          for (let obj in matter.footprint) {
            return matter.footprint[obj] === this.currentFilter;
          }
        });
      }
```

It's working but only with the first string of the array which is stored under my blog post tag

```
<v-chip v-bind:class="{ active: currentFilter === 'all' }" v-on:click="setFilter('all')" color="primary" small class="mt-3">
            All
          </v-chip>
          <v-chip v-for="footprint in footprints" :key="footprint" v-bind:class="{ active: currentFilter === footprint }" v-on:click="setFilter(footprint)" color="primary" small class="mt-3">
            {{ footprint }}
          </v-chip>
```

When I console.log(matter.footprint) I get all arrays from all posts instead of getting the array of the selected post.

```
return this.matters.filter((matter) => {
        console.log(matter.footprint)
          for (let obj in matter.footprint) {

            return matter.footprint[obj] === this.currentFilter;
          }
        });
```

log:

```
(3) ["Nature", "Ecosystems", "Ecology"]
Matter.vue?9a91:136 ["Writings"]
Matter.vue?9a91:136 ["Chips"]
Matter.vue?9a91:136 ["Analogy"]
Matter.vue?9a91:136 (2) ["Ecology", "Humanitarian"]
Matter.vue?9a91:136 ["Media Interaction Design"]
Matter.vue?9a91:136 Glacier
Matter.vue?9a91:136 ["Bugs"]
Matter.vue?9a91:136 ["Design thinking"]
Matter.vue?9a91:136 undefined
Matter.vue?9a91:136 ["nature"]
Matter.vue?9a91:136 (2) ["arduino", "open source"]
Matter.vue?9a91:136 ["Intelligence Collective"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

I was inspired by this thread [How to filter posts in Vue with components and v-bind:class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61166696/how-to-filter-posts-in-vue-with-components-and-v-bindclass/63989821#63989821)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filteredMatters: function () {
        if (this.currentFilter === "all") {
          return this.matters;
        }
        return this.matters.filter((matter) => {
          let footprint = []
          for (let obj in matter.footprint) {
            footprint.push(matter.footprint[obj])
          }
          return footprint.some(item => item === this.currentFilter)
        });
      }
```